# How to scrape all the children tags of a specific tag, from google scholar website

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from google scholar profile, let's say [this site](https://scholar.google.com.au/citations?user=zD0vtfwAAAAJ&hl=en#d=gs_md_cita-d&u=%2Fcitations%3Fview_op%3Dview_citation%26hl%3Den%26user%3DzD0vtfwAAAAJ%26citation_for_view%3DzD0vtfwAAAAJ%3Ad1gkVwhDpl0C%26tzom%3D-330)

While going through the website. I want to scrape all the co-author's names which is in the `div` tag with class `gsc_vcd_value` but I'm not able to do that directly so I tried going in the sequence. what my exact problem is that till the `div` tag with id `gs_md_cita-d-bdy`, I'm able to scrape everything i.e (all the children tags" contained in the specific tag. but afterwards when I try to do the same for `div` tag with id `gs_md_cita-l`, I'm only getting the tag itself in return. I'm not getting the children tags in return, I'm only getting the tag itself. Please suggest me what am I missing?

when I try to print r_tag, I get

```
<div class="gs_md_bdy" id="gs_md_cita-d-bdy"><style>#gs_md_cita-  

d{width:90%;max-width:1000px;}.gs_el_ph #gs_md_cita-d{width:100%;max-    

width:none;}#gs_md_cita-d .gs_md_prg{min-height:600px;}#gs_md_cita-

title,#gs_md_cita-b-edit,#gs_md_cita-b-trash,#gs_md_cita-

b-upload,#gs_md_cita-b-rstr,#gs_md_cita-b-delf,#gs_md_cita-

b-save{display:none;}.gs_md_cita-view #gs_md_cita-b-edit,.gs_md_cita-        view 

#gs_md_cita-b-trash,.gs_md_cita-view.gs_md_cita-allow_upload            #gs_md_cita- b-upload,.gs_md_cita-upload #gs_md_cita-title,.gs_md_cita-trash #gs_md_cita-

b-rstr,.gs_md_cita-trash #gs_md_cita-b-delf,.gs_md_cita-edit #gs_md_cita-

b-save{display:inline-block;}#gs_md_cita-b-trash,#gs_md_cita-

b-upload,#gs_md_cita-b-delf{margin-left:16px;}</style><div aria-

live="assertive" id="gs_md_cita-l"></div></div>...
```

and so on, so basically everything in the tag like the children tags and all 
but when I try to print s_tag I only get

```
[<div aria-live="assertive" id="gs_md_cita-l"></div>]

[<div aria-live="assertive" id="gs_md_cita-l"></div>]

[<div aria-live="assertive" id="gs_md_cita-l"></div>]
```

only the tag value  for every iteration.

```
import bs4
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 

import urllib.request


class Scraper():
    def __init__(self, url, maxP):
        self.url= url
        self.maxP = maxP
    def f(self):
        for i in range(0,1000,100):
            if (self.maxP<i):
                pageSize=i

        for j in range(0, pageSize, 100):

            S_url=self.url + "&cstart=" + str(j) +"&pagesize=100"

            my_url = uReq(S_url)
            page_html = my_url.read()
            my_url.close()

            page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")

            aTag = page_soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'gsc_rsb_std'})

            Titles = page_soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'gsc_a_t'})

            Citations = page_soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'gsc_a_c'})

            Years = page_soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'gsc_a_y'})

            info_page = page_soup.findAll('a', {'class' : 'gsc_a_at'})

            for author in info_page:
                Author_names_link = author["data-href"]
                user=Author_names_link[53:65]
                n_input=Author_names_link[-12:]

                n_author_url="https://scholar.google.com.au
/citations?user="+user+"&hl=en#d=gs_md_cita-
  d&u=%2Fcitations%3Fview_op%3Dview_citation%26hl%3Den%26user%3D"+user+"%26cit
ation_for_view%3D"+user+"%3A"+n_input+"%26tzom%3D-330"

                author_url=uReq(n_author_url)

                n_page=author_url.read()

                author_url.close()

                n_page_soup=soup(n_page, "html.parser")

                n_tag=n_page_soup

                m_tag=n_tag.findAll('div', {'id': 'gs_top'})

                for i in m_tag:

                    p_tag=i.findAll('div', {'data-h': '800'})

                    for j in p_tag:

                        q_tag=j.findAll('div', {'id': 'gs_md_cita-d'})

                        for k in q_tag:

                            r_tag=k.findAll('div', {'id': 'gs_md_cita-            d-bdy'})

                            for l in r_tag:

                                s_tag=l.findAll('div', {'id':     'gs_md_cita-l'})
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the current output for a single container along with your expected output?

Comment: Hi @SIM, I tried editing my post as I thought you suggested. please review.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to visually grab CSS selectors from your browser. Also, make sure you're using [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) to present that a "real" user makes a request, not a bot/script so websites won't block your request. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Note that this is the most basic form of bypassing blocks from websites.

[Code and example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/How-to-scrape-all-the-children-tags-of-a-specific-tag#main.py) using `bs4` or `parsel`:

```py
from parsel import Selector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "user": "zD0vtfwAAAAJ",                           # user ID
    "citation_for_view": "zD0vtfwAAAAJ:d1gkVwhDpl0C", # user ID + citation ID
    "hl": "en",                                       # language
    "view_op": "view_citation"                        # option to view citation
}

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582",
}

html = requests.get("https://scholar.google.com.au/citations", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup, selector = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml"), Selector(html.text)

# using parsel
co_authors = selector.css(".gs_scl:nth-child(1) .gsc_oci_value::text").getall()
print(co_authors)

# or using beautifulsoup
bs4_co_authors = [co_author.text for co_author in soup.select(".gs_scl:nth-child(1) .gsc_oci_value")]
print(bs4_co_authors)


# output both from parsel and bs4
'''
['Christoph Benzmüller, Michael Kohlhase']
['Christoph Benzmüller, Michael Kohlhase']
'''
```

---

If you would like to scrape other Google Scholar information, I have several dedicated blog posts, for example [Scrape historic 2017-2021 Organic, Cite Google Scholar results to CSV, SQLite using Python and SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-historic-google-scholar-results-using-python/) with in-depth explanation and code snippets.